# Create all possible variations of string Python

Tags: python, string, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I met a problem, I need to create a list of all possible variations of string. I had already tried some methods from itertools, like `[''.join(i) for i in itertools.permutations('abc')]` or

`(comb = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement('abc',3)]`   but they have a bit different result, as i was expected. I need ALL variations, so permutation isn't the way to do it. Combinations with replacement were quite good, but there were missing some subsequence
The result of this operation is:

```
aab
aac
abb
abc
acc
bbb
bbc
bcc
ccc
```

But i need output '**aba', 'acb' 'bab',etc** as well (Need to cover all possible variants)
Maybe im missing another method in itertools, that would help me?
Thanks for any help and advice

Comment: Have you tried getting all permutations of each with-replacement combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `itertools.product` with as many iterables as the size of your string:

```py
from itertools import product

s = 'abc'
ss = [s] * len(s)
for r in product(*ss):
    print(''.join(r))

aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa
bab
bac
bba
bbb
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

Comment: `product` allows you the even simpler: `for r in product(s, repeat=len(s)):`